# Implementation of breadth-first search in tcl

Tags: tcl

I am trying to implement **breadth-first search algorithm** but I am unable to implement , and I am new user of TCL can any one help me to implement this algorithm in tcl.

Comment: If you're after tcl, why have you tagged this question `perl` then?

Comment: Which tree or graph implementation are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I think we need a bit more detail before we can help.

So, are we are talking about a graph, if so what type? The simplest would be a undirected graph with no edge weights but is this the case?

Do you have a data structure for the graph, if so what is it?

Finally why are you re-inventing the wheel? Tcllib has the struct::graph package which implements breadth first search, see the **walk** command.  Can you use this or the algorithms in the struct::graph::op package to do what you want.

Comment: whether the graph has cycles may also be a concern

Comment: I am trying it for undirected graph with no edge weights, I haven't tried the package ur suggested

Comment: Hello all, 

Thanx those who all are replied my first question.

I have implemented BFS to reach till the target node while moving from the graph till the end node I am storing all the node (say Parent Node) and their out coming nodes (child nodes) in array of tcl. But Now I am unable to retrieve all paths between two nodes.


Wating for Your answer......

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for files instead of generic objects, look up the command for_recursive_glob in the Tclx package. Here is a quick example:

```
package require Tclx
for_recursive_glob fileName {/path/to/dir1 /to/dir2} {*.txt *.doc} { puts $fileName }
```

The document said for_recursive_glob use breadth-first algorithm. If you want to exit prematurely (i.e. found what you were looking for), use the 'break' command to exit the for loop:

```
package require Tclx
for_recursive_glob fileName {/path/to/dir1 /to/dir2} {*.txt *.doc} { 
    puts $fileName
    if {[string match *myfile*]} { break }
}
```